# Mayday tileset does not render correctly on Linux

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm using PyLNP 0.9.5a on Ubuntu. I've installed the Mayday tileset and generated a new world, but the characters seem all messed up.

Here, the dwarves are all squid-looking and the animals are only symbols:
[image]

I also installed PyLNP in Windows 7, and it renders everything correctly there. Is there something wrong with the mayday pack or PyLNP on Linux?

Comment: Ooh!  Chthonic-Fortress!

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, those "squid-looking" things are dwarf heads. I just downloaded the pack and that seems to be exactly what it's meant to look like. Your Windows install must be the old version, which looked different and had more tiles for animals.

The GoblinArt site has some more information about the pack, possibly including these changes. You can also e-mail the pack's creator if you have further questions.